# AMP-HTML - CSS syntax error incomplete declaration

Tags: css, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I'm trying to build an AMP page, and I'm having some problems validating some css. I have a H1 that has 4 words that I need to alternate. I did that by creating 4 spans inside with the words and animating their opacity to show/hide the ones I need (opacity is one of the whitelisted properties that you can animate with keyframes so there should't be any problems with that). It all works as expected, but the code isn't beeing validated by the [AMP validator](https://validator.ampproject.org/).

I get this error

> CSS syntax error in tag 'style[amp-keyframes]' - incomplete
>   declaration.

for this css

```
 <style amp-keyframes>
      @keyframes words {
        0% { opacity: 1; }
        25% { opacity: 1; }
        26% { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 0; }
      }
    </style>
```

Any ideeas why that happens or maybe another solution for this?

Comment: Strangest thing is that directly copy-pasting you code on the amp validator shows no errors. So must be on the way that tag interacts with the rest of your document

Comment: I'm working locally and tryed validating in two ways: with  #development=1 in the adress bar and online through Ngrok. Same result: CSS syntax error in tag 'style[amp-keyframes]' - incomplete declaration.

Comment: By looking at the keyframes docs in https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-animation#keyframes, would that work using <style amp-custom> and then @keyframes inside the tag as you are already doing?

Comment: Tried that too. Doesn't work. It's probably a bug. I managed to get a similar result using their "amp-animation" .. element but with a lot more code as I can't seem to use percentages in the keyframes. They automatically divide the animation time between keyframes so I had to use a lot more of them to get something similar.

Comment: needs to be `<style amp-custom>@keyframe ...`

Comment: It's <style amp-custom>@keyframe**s** , and I said I already tested that. In the meantime I found my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Evrika!

Well... this has got to be the most annoying bug I've encountered. Apparently this is ok:

```
  @keyframes word {
    25% { content:"some text";}
    50% { content:"other text";}
    75% { content:"text";}
  }
```

but this is not:

```
  @keyframes word {
    25% { content:"some text";  }
    50% { content:"other text"; }
    75% { content:"text";       }
  }
```

LE: Found the real problem: between the end of the keyframe "`;`" and the clossing braket "`}`", I had a combination of spaces and non-breaking spaces. Removed those, and now it works.